# Change sequence of column in yii framework (CActiveRecords)

Tags: php, yii, cactiverecord

The output grid has following sequence of columns of a table -> B, C, D, E, A (same sequence as in table in database). But I need this sequence of columns -> A, B, C, D, E. I know how to do this using sql query. But I have to do this in Yii framework(I am very new to Yii framework).

This is my code for MyClass which extends CActiveRecords

```
class Myclass extends CActiveRecord
{  
public function tableName()
{
    return 'dbName.dbTableName';
}
public function rules()
{
    //Some rules
}
public function relations()
{
    //Some modified relations
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'a' => 'A',
        'b' => 'B',
        'c' => 'C',
        'd' => 'D',
        'e' => 'E',
    );
}
public function search()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('a',$this->A);
    $criteria->compare('b',$this->B);
    $criteria->compare('c',$this->C,true);
    $criteria->compare('d',$this->D,true);
    $criteria->compare('e',$this->E,true);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
public function getDbConnection()
{
    return Yii::app()->db1;
}
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
}
```

1) Is there any inbuilt function in Yii Framework which can re-arrange the sequence of columns of according to my needs.

2) I should re-arrange the columns sequence here or somewhere else. I mean is this the right class for re-arranging column sequence.

3) Can anyone suggest me some good tutorial for advance Yii framework ( Video Tutorial, if possible).

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Why is the order important? I don't know any method to rearrange the order in Yii directly but I have never come to a situation where this is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Add this:

   $criteria->select = 'a, b, c, d, e'; // columns in the desired sequence
2. If you always want this sequence when using the `search()` method, this is the right place.
3. Sorry, can't really help you here. Learn to read the Yii Framework documents and you can almost find everything you need.